# Quick question about showing surjection for the following homomorphic map

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Can someone please comment on whether my solution to the following is correct.

Let $h:\mathbb{Z}_{16}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4$ be defined by $h([a]_{16})=[3a]_4$.  I want to show that this map is surjective.

Suppose $x\in \mathbb{Z}_{4}$, then $x=[3a]_4$ which implies $x\equiv 3a \pmod 4$, multiplying both sides by $3$, then $a\equiv 3x \pmod 4$, and is the $a$ we are looking for for any $x\in \mathbb{Z}_{4}$.  Hence $h$ is surjective.

Comment: Did you mean to take $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$? Also, the way you write looks like you start by asserting it is in the image, rather than proving it is.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin isn't the way to show a function is surjective, where $f:A\rightarrow B$ is to assume for any $y\in B$, there exist an $a\in A$ so that $f(a)=y$.   In the case of my problem, I assume that $x\in \mathbb{Z_{4}}$ then find out a specific $a\in\mathbb{Z_{16}}$

Comment: First, you start by taking $x$ in the domain and then saying it equals something in the codomain. Look at the index in the first formula of your second paragraph.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes i meant $\mathbb{Z_{4}}$.  I made the necessary correction.  Other than that, is my proof correct?

Comment: Second, no, you do not **assume** it is equal to $f(a)$ for some $a$. You want to *prove* it is equal to $f(a)$. So you start with $y$ in the codomain, and must **prove** there exists $a$ in the domain such that $f(a)=y$. You do not assume such an $a$ exists. That is affirming the consequent.

Comment: Your argument is both poorly phrased (see above) and incomplete. I do not see a proof that *any* solution to your congruence will yield an equivalence class in the domain that will map to $x$. You assert necessity, but never prove sufficiency.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin over here at Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function it states..."that is, for every $y$, there is an $x$ such that $f(x) = y$".  I am not sure what you mean i proved necessity but not sufficiency.  I assume that $x\in \mathbb{Z_4}$, and so $[x]_4=[3x]_4$ which implies $x\equiv 3a \pmod 4$.  I then isolate $a$ by multiplying 3 on both sides to get $a\equiv 3x \pmod 4$ which implies $a=3x+4t$ for $t\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I did left out the bit that since $4|16$, then $4|(a-3x)$, implies, $(a-3x)|16$, hence $a\equiv 3x \pmod {16}$

Comment: "and so $[x]=[3a]$" is assuming what you are trying to prove: that $x$ is in the image of $h$. You are misinterpreting Wikipedia. It does not tell you to *assume* it is in the image, it tells you that you must **conclude** it is in the image. From your unwarranted assumption that it is in the image, you derive a condition that $a$ must satisfy. But you never show that if $a$ satisfies the condition, then $h([a]_{16})=x$. So you prove necessity, but you need sufficiency.

Comment: You have a bunch of one-directional implications. What you end up with is that **IF** $x=h([a])$, **THEN** $a\equiv 3x\pmod{4}$. What you want to prove is that there exists some $a$ such that $h([a])=x$. You do not prove that. What you have now is a bunch of *candidates* for possible $a$ (necessity: *if* $a$ works, *then* it must satisfy the congruence). You are missing a verification that some such $a$ **WILL** actually map to $x$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin do you mean:  then if $a\equiv 3x \pmod 4$, then $a\equiv 3x \pmod {16}$ and $h([a]_{16})=h([3x]_{16})=[3(3x)]_4=[x]_4$.

Comment: No, I don't mean that because it is false.  $1\equiv 3(3)\pmod{4}$, but $1\not\equiv 3(3)\pmod{16}$. Why would I mean something so obviously false? I mean exactly what I've said now three times, and here is the fouth and last: you **never show** that if $a$ satisfies the condition you derive then this *implies* that $h([a])=x$. Showing *that* is your goal. You only show the converse: **if** $h([a])=x$, then $a$ satisfies the condition. That is not what you need to prove. I cannot say it more clearly, and there is no point in going for a fifth repetition, so this is my last comment.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin can I ask, if you can show me how to prove surjection for this question please.

Answer (score 1):

We only need to show that multiplication by $3$ is a surjection, then the claim follows.

Indeed, take any $[a]_4\in \mathbb{Z}_4$ represented by the integer $a$. By definition $gcd(3,4)=1$ so there are $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $3x+4y=1$ by Bezouts lemma, so $3ax+4ay = a$ now reduce this equation $\mod 4$ and you are done. Here in this particular example we have that $3\cdot 3-2\cdot 4=1$.

Comment: did you meant gcd instead of lcm.  Also what does the phrase reduce the equation mod 4 in this context.

Comment: Indeed I meant gcd. The phrase means that if we have $3ax+4ay=a$ in the integers we can also view this equation in $\mathbb{Z}_4$. I also made the original answer a tad more precise.

Comment: You also need to show reduction from mod 16 to mod 4 is surjective, though perhaps you are taking that for granted, seeing how it is easy.

Answer (score 1):

First some preliminary comments:

Although you never address it, I am going to guess that you verified that this function is *well defined*. This is important. You need to show that if $[a]_{16}=[b]_{16}$, then $[3a]_{4} = [3b]_{4}$, so that the value of the map does not depend on the representative chosen.

This holds, since
$$\begin{align*}
[a]_{16}=[b]_{16}&\iff a\equiv b\pmod{16}\\
&\implies a\equiv b\pmod{4}\\
&\iff 3a\equiv 3b\pmod{4}
\end{align*}$$
with the last equivalence because $3$ is invertible modulo $4$. So the map is well defined.

Now, as to your attempt at proving surjectivity. To show that a function $f\colon A\to B$ is surjective we must show that:

> For all $b\in B$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$.

The basic way of doing this is to start with $b\in B$, and then produce or find some $a\in A$ and verifying that in fact $f(a)=b$ holds. There may be other ways of doing it in specific instances (for example, vector spaces you may verify that the image contains a basis of the codomain, and thus that the image must be the whole codomain), but that's the basic thing.

Now, this process of showing surjectivity often has two parts: analysis and synthesis.

In the analysis part, we assume that we have already found some $a$ with $f(a)=b$, and we see what conclusions we can derive about $a$ from this fact. This will establish *necessary* conditions that $a$ must satisfy in order to be a preimage of $b$. Because we are saying "**if** $a$ is a preimage of $b$, **then** $a$ must satisfy the following conditions."

Once we have completed the analysis part, we perform synthesis: we show that in fact there is an $a$ with $f(a)=b$, usually by taking the necessary conditions we found during analysis, and showing that in fact they are also **sufficient**: "**if** $a$ satisfies the following conditions, **then** $f(a)=b$."

It is really the synthesis that we are after, not the analysis. The analysis is the "scratch work" to achieve the synthesis.

You only performed the analysis. You said, paraphrased:

> Let $[x]_{4}\in \mathbb{Z}_4$, and assume that there is an $[a]_{16}\in\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ such that $h([a]_{16})=[x]_4$. We have:
> $$\begin{align*}
> h([a]_{16}) = [x]_4 &\implies [3a]_{4}=[x]_4\\
> &\implies 3a\equiv x\pmod{4}\\
> &\implies 3(3a)\equiv 3x\pmod{4}\\
> &\implies a\equiv 3x\pmod{4}.
> \end{align*}$$

And you stopped there. Thus, you concluded that if $[a]_{16}$ is a preimage of $x$, then it must be the case that $a\equiv 3x\pmod{4}$.

What you are missing is a verification that in fact **if** $a\equiv 3x\pmod{4}$, then $h([a]_{16})=[x]_4$. That is, you are missing the synthesis.

To that end, pick any integer $x$ representing $[x]_4$, and let $a=3x$. We now consider $[a]_{16}=[3x]_{16}$: we have:
$$h([a]_{16}) = h([3x]_{16}) = [3(3x)]_{4} = [9x]_{4} = [x]_4.$$
Thus, $[a]_{16}$ is indeed a preimage of $[x]_4$. This proves that for every $[x]_{4}\in\mathbb{Z}_4$ there exists $[a]_{16}\in\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ such that $h([a]_{16}) = [x]_4$, so $h$ is surjective.

---

*Often* people skip the synthesis because the analysis consists of reversible steps. That is, the synthesis establishes an equivalence instead of an implication. For example, suppose we want to show that $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=3x-1$ is surjective. To that end, let $a\mathbb{R}$. Then, performing analysis, we might say
$$\begin{align*}
f(x)=a &\implies 3x-1 = a\\
&\implies 3x=a+1\\
&\implies x=\frac{1}{3}(a+1).
\end{align*}$$
But then we might realize: "Wait! Each of those steps is actually an 'if and only if'. What we actually have is:
$$\begin{align*}
f(x)=a &\iff 3x-1 = a\\
&\iff 3x=a+1\\
&\iff x=\frac{1}{3}(a+1).
\end{align*}$$
so that $f(x)=a$ **if and only if** $x=\frac{1}{3}(a+1)$." So we do not actually have to spell out the synthesis, since we can do the synthesis simply by reading the chain of equalities "from bottom to top".

This happens to be the case with your derivation: all the steps are actually reversible, *but you did not state them that way*. That means you must either verify that they are reversible, or else you must perform the synthesis explicitly. Otherwise, your work in incomplete.

---

Why does this matter? Because sometimes the analysis is not fully reversible.  So you must check to see if the conditions you have obtained are not just necessary, but also sufficient. Many people forget this, or are not used to checking this, often leading to "extraneous solutions" or "weird answers". See for example, [this previous discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4293918/742), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3347853/742), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3464756/742), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1716731/742), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3648460/742), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2814013/742), etc.

Comment: my profuse apologies, I did not know what you meant was that I had to substitute back into the function to get back the identity.  Also, since for the question, the fact that the domain and codomain involved different congruence,, with the codomain being mod 4 and domain mod 16, I thought i had to make use of these two facts since I had $x\equiv 3a \pmod 4$ or equivalently $a\equiv 3s \pmod 4$, I had to related the values of either $a$ or $x$ to mod 16.  Two other things are that I did not know that when I have $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $x=[3a]_4$ which means $[x]_4\equiv[3a]_4$ ...

Comment: ....it is in the context of the preimage of $h$.  Lastly, I am not sure whether  I should use (1) $a\equiv 3x \pmod 4$ or (2) $[x]_4\equiv[3a]_4$ .  Since using (1) and plugging back into the domain of $h$, $3x$ for $a$, I get back  $[3x]_4$, but if I use (2) and I plug in $3x$ for $a$ in the domain of $h$, I get back $[3\cdot 3x]_4 =[x]_4$

Comment: thank you for the detail write up.  I also see now that showing that $h$ is well defined saves me the trouble of worrying about whether going from mod 4 to mod 16 is valid when plugging back values into the domain to check for surjectivity.